# The method to download or extract data from free bloomberg web chart

Tags: web, charts, web-scraping, extract, bloomberg

I find bloomberg providing information about some  interesting quotes for example:

http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/JPMVXYG7:IND/chart/

The question is how could I extract the data like daily data from this chart, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this into excel easily using the Bloomberg addin, this will give you a full years history.

```
=BDH("JPMVXYG7 Index","mid","2011-03-24","2012-03-23")
```

Comment: do I need bloomberg account, is this totally free?

Comment: Yes you need a Bloomberg account & no it is not free - Bloomberg's business is built on charging users for data, they don't give it away for free.

Comment: Thanks, man....the day will come when I use bloomberg as a subscriber:) Have a nice day